# GPU Profiling hints in Marshmallow, Sync time

Tags: android, profiling, gpu, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am profiling the gpu usage of an android app I'm making which uses the camera as well as opengl.  I'm seeing a number of "slow" frames and in each one the culprit appears to be a long "sync" time. What does this mean and how can I attack it?

[image: GPU profiling graph under normal application load]

Comment: I'm seeing the same. With Lollipop on another device I don't have those peaks.